# Equivalence De Rham and Dolbeault groupoids

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, groupoids

I believe there is an error or incompleteness in Goldman's and Xia's proof of the equivalence of the De Rham and Dolbeault groupoids, contained in

> *Rank One Higgs Bundles and Representations of Fundamental Groups of Riemann Surfaces*, Memoirs of the American Mathematical Society. **193** (2008), no. 904 , viii+69pp, arXiv:[math/0402429](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402429), [AMS bookstore](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-193-904/), [authors' pdf](https://www.math.umd.edu/~wmg/higgs.pdf).

On proof of Theorem 4.1.9 (p.33) they want to prove that 
$\text{Mor}(D_1,D_2)\to \text{Mor}(S(D_1),S(D_2))$ is bijective.

They do that by proving that $\text{Mor}(D_1,D_2)$ and $\text{Mor}(S(D_1),S(D_2))$ are either $\varnothing$ or $\mathbb{C}^*$ depending on whether $D_1$ and $D_2$ (or $S(D_1)$ and $S(D_2)$) are equivalent.

This however does not exclude the possibility that $\text{Mor}(D_1,D_2)\to \text{Mor}(S(D_1),S(D_2))$ is actually the empty morphism $\varnothing \to \mathbb{C}^*$. For that they would need that $S_*$ is injective, but they do not prove that, in fact that is the purpose of the Corollary 4.1.10.

Am I getting something wrong? How can I prove that $S_*$ is injective?

Comment: I put in the full reference to the monograph, as the pdf link you gave could evaporate at any time. Looking at the pdf, it's not 100% clear what on pg33 you are referring to: is it the proof of Theorem 4.1.9 that you are uncertain about?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, proof of Theorem 4.1.9.